# Trying to learn how enchanced input works in UE 5.3

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I newbie in c++ and unreal engine and im trying to learn new way of creating controls instead of using deprecated ones. Currently my code looks like this:

```
// Copyright Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.


#include "CryptRaiderPlayerController.h"
#include "EnhancedInputSubsystems.h"
#include "EnhancedInputComponent.h"

void ACryptRaiderPlayerController::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    // get the enhanced input subsystem
    if (UEnhancedInputLocalPlayerSubsystem* Subsystem = ULocalPlayer::GetSubsystem<UEnhancedInputLocalPlayerSubsystem>(GetLocalPlayer()))
    {
        // add the mapping context so we get controls
        Subsystem->AddMappingContext(InputMappingContext, 0);

        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("BeginPlay"));
    }
}

void ACryptRaiderPlayerController::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    UEnhancedInputComponent* Input = Cast<UEnhancedInputComponent>(PlayerInputComponent);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Display, TEXT("Grab pre-clicked!"));

    Input->BindAction(GrabAction , ETriggerEvent::Triggered, this, &ACryptRaiderPlayerController::GrabberTest)
}

void ACryptRaiderPlayerController::GrabberTest(const FInputActionInstance& Instance)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Display, TEXT("Grab clicked!"));
}
```

I don't know how to get rid of of this error: identifier "GrabAction" is undefined
I also don't know what I should put in that place.
Both logs doesn't logging currently anything.

I have created IA and IMC:[IA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc6Ru.png) [IMC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rHUn.png)

I expect to print some values at first. Next I want to make my character grab something, but I don't wanna to give to much details at beginning to avoid getting out of the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to create an Action.

More you can found here UE Enhanced Input Systems Tutorial. Also and how to setup move and look:

https://nightails.com/2022/10/16/unreal-engine-enhanced-input-system-in-c/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).